# integrated windows authentication in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, wia

I want to add integrated windows authentication feature to my asp.net app. I dont know how to add it. I am developing it with C#. Please help me out.

Comment: Check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

Comment: i am using .net 4.0 and i am not able to use MVC 4 architecture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a default project's web.config file, there should be an `<authentication mode="x">` element.  Change the mode to "Windows" and you should be all set -- but this just allows users from your network to access the app.  You'd still have to create roles and/or groups to prevent access to certain features or areas.

Comment: thank you for your reply..it's done now. Can you just tell me how can I get the login pop-up?

Comment: If you're on the domain in which the app is being run, use Firefox.  I think IE and Chrome automatically pass your credentials in.  Maybe using IE's "In Private" browsing or Chrome's "Incognito" modes might force you to manually authenticate.  Other than that, you'll have to do some sort user switching capability.  On machines outside the host server's network/domain (connected ADs, actually), you may be prompted for credentials.  E.g., a machine at home that is not on the domain or VPN may prompt you because your home machine's credentials aren't valid on the hosting network.